# comparing mean values of a positive functions

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $D$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $A\subset B\subset D$ measurable sets. Let $f:D\rightarrow [0.+\infty)$ be a measurable function (or even locally integrable) and $\lambda$ designate the $n-$dimensional Lebesgue measure. Can we say that 
$$\frac{1}{\lambda(A)} \int_{A}fd\lambda\leq \frac{1}{\lambda(B)} \int_{B}fd\lambda?$$  Why yes, why no?(exclude $A=\emptyset$)

Answer (score 1):

It is false. The function $f$ could be concentrated in $A$, thus averaging over some larger set you will only dilute it. As an extreme example, take 
$$
f(x)=\chi_A(x).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which are the conditions under which the inequality holds?

Comment: You should give some condition that rules out functions that are concentrated on $A$, but frankly I don't think that a nice enough set of such conditions exists.

Comment: You could say something in special cases, though. If $A$ and $B$ are concentric balls and $f$ is radially symmetric and monotone nondecreasing then the inequality should hold, I guess.